# Web Service hosted in IIS7.0 is not getting refreshed

Tags: web-services, iis-7, hosting

I hosted one web service .NET 4.0 in IIS 7.0. I used my own Application Pool with .NET 4.0. After hosting I changed some code in web service application. Web service application is running fine but hosted service in IIS7 is not working.

The method which I am trying to fetch is showing value success but not showing any detail result. Suppose I am trying to fetch data from one table. When I am running this service from application it is showing table data but when I am trying to run it from IIS7, it is only showing success message without data.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your resultclass needs some attributes.

the class itself needs to be a `[DataContract]` and all members you want to show (properties) need to be `[DataMember]`

This is most likely the cause of the issue.

So in example:

```
[DataContract]
public class C1 {
    [DataMember]
    public int prop1 {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: This is not WCF. It is web service and [WebMethod] attribute is already there. This web service is working fine and hosted perfectly in other place but it is not hosting properly in our development environment.

Comment: It's hard to really answer this then with so little information. I'm sorry.